# SQL Server stored procedure with user-defined table type

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server with a parameter `@Files` which is a user-defined table type. I get an error while executing it from C# code:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Table-valued parameter 3 ("@Files"), row 0, column 0: Data type 0xF3 (user-defined table type) has a non-zero length database name specified.  Database name is not allowed with a table-valued parameter, only schema name and type name are valid.'

This is my C# code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ComputerId", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("FolderId", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("FilePath", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Size", typeof(long));
dt.Columns.Add("LastWriteTimeUtc", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add("ReadOnly", typeof(bool));

foreach (var item in listFileInformation)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(1, 1, item.FilePath, item.FileName, item.Size, item.LastWriteUTC, item.ReaddOnly);
}

databaseHelper.AddParameter("@ComputerId", 1);
databaseHelper.AddParameter("@FolderId", 1);

SqlParameter tableTypeParam = new SqlParameter("@Files", SqlDbType.Structured)
                                  {
                                      TypeName = "Inbox.dbo.EngComputerFileTableType",
                                      Value = dt
                                  };
databaseHelper.AddParameter(tableTypeParam);

databaseHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("InsertEngComputerFiles", System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, System.Data.ConnectionState.Open);

databaseHelper.connection.Close();
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertEngComputerFiles]
    @ComputerId BIGINT,
    @FolderId BIGINT,
    @Files [dbo].[EngComputerFileTableType] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO
        [Inbox].[dbo].[EngComputerFile] (
            [ComputerId], [FolderId], [FilePath], [FileName],
            [Size], [LastWriteTimeUtc], [ReadOnly])
        SELECT
            @ComputerId, @FolderId, [FilePath], [FileName],
            [Size], [LastWriteTimeUtc], [ReadOnly]
        FROM
            @Files;

    UPDATE [Inbox].[dbo].[EngComputer]
    SET [LastScanTimeStampUtc] = SYSUTCDATETIME()
    WHERE [ComputerId] = @ComputerId;
END
```

Comment: Why do you say `TypeName = "Inbox.dbo.EngComputerFileTableType"` instead of just `TypeName = "dbo.EngComputerFileTableType"`? The type has to be in the same database as the stored procedure you're calling for any of this to work, so the database prefix is unnecessary (and the error message is telling you that it's not only unnecessary but invalid).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for your response !! However I have already tried dbo.EngComputerFileTableType but it is also giving error 'Invalid object name 'Inbox.dbo.EngComputerFile'.'

Comment: `dbo.EngComputerFile` <> `dbo.EngComputerFileTableType ` @MiralShah .

Comment: @Larnu ya true !!!

Comment: Do NOT use 3-part names generally without a very good reason. Your connection should determine the database context. As a database migrates between environments, the names of those databases often change. Using 3-part names will only create more work to support this very common practice.

Comment: @SMor you mean to say we should you use EngComputerFileTableType only

Comment: No. 2-part names are good. 1-part and 3-part names are bad except in very specific edge cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message says it all
you need to change this line

```
SqlParameter tableTypeParam = new SqlParameter("@Files", SqlDbType.Structured)
{
//TypeName = "Inbox.dbo.EngComputerFileTableType",
TypeName = "dbo.EngComputerFileTableType",

Value = dt
};
```